# JQuery selected text node but cannot preform any css function on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the text:

```
<div id="wrapper1">Welcome to our website<span class="inner">, </span>Bud!</div>
```

So after selecting **"bud!"** with:

```
var elementOne = $('#wrapper1')[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
```

When I do `elementOne.css("color", "red");` I am getting an error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: elementOne.css is not a function

How can I preform css on this variable?

> **EDIT:** Please note that I am not interested to add a span and this was given to me by someone as a quiz test and there is a way to preform this **without adding the span**

trying with wrap, offered by great Scott (he gave me a link to the Jquery wrap function)

> TRIAL:
>   tried with this:

```
var elementTwo = $('#wrapper1');
elementTwo.html(elementTwo.text().replace(/(\w+?)$/, '<span style="color: red;">$2</span>'));
```

still not working.

Comment: How do you expect to apply CSS to a random text node??? You at least need to wrap it in a span or something. You can't just apply CSS properties to text, they require some HTML element to select.

Comment: @Scott ok, don't take it personally, I just want to color bud! in red, sheese.

Comment: Uhm.. nothing personal... just as I explained, you can't apply css properties in thin air... they need an html selector to be applied to... such as a span.

Comment: So you're saying that, that specific part cannot be colored in red? :) that doesn't make sense. I want to do it without spanning it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying... you **can not** just randomly apply CSS in the middle of a text string. There **must** be some HTML tag to select.

Comment: @Scott I would bet you that there would be someone who would know how to do this. If you don't know how to do this, it doesn't mean it can't be done.

Comment: Or I do know how to do this (as I've described) so I *know* this can't be done. Note the answers coming in.. all add a span....  Nice attitude.. good luck to you!

Comment: @Scott nothing to do with any attitude, my bet still stands, it can be done without spanning the element.

Comment: don't know why I bother... but........you can add a span and never touch the actual HTML...... But some tag, any tag, is **required**.

Comment: @Scott it's because you care. In anycase, this is a quiz I got from my senior dev and he insisted there is a solution without wrapping it in a span. Mind you that the text is still wrapped in a div and is the last child node (if you noticed) Is there a way to wrap that specific part in a span with jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @Scott thanks for the link, check out my edit.

Comment: so we bet around $100 @Scott? :) I answered my own question.

Comment: @clusterBuddy what `.wrap` does is add the span that you insist should not be added.. so listen to @scott.

Comment: "it cannot be done!!!!" -scott. "Oh wait, wrap()" -scott, latent response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Your html

```
<div id="wrapper1">Welcome to our website<span class="inner">, </span>Bud!</span></div>
```

Your javascript

```
var elementOne = $('#wrapper1')[0].childNodes[2];
$(elementOne).wrap("<div>").css("color","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper1">Welcome to our website<span class="inner">, </span><span class="bud">Bud!</span></div>


$(".bud").css("color", "red");
```

this works fine, you should not apply css function on a text node, it only works on jQuery object.

hope this can help

Answer (score -1):

I've found the answer:

```
var elementOne = $('#wrapper1')[0].childNodes[2];
$(elementOne).wrap("<span style='color: red;'>");
```